# formulating a differential equation using volume and time

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

One manufacturer estimates that the growth rate of sales volume V (in thousands of units)
is proportional to the square root of the time elapsed (in months) since the marketing of a good.
At the time of this marketing, the sales volume is zero. After 16 months, this volume drops to 100.

Formulate the differential equation describing the change in sales volume V (t) in
time function

so i found $\dfrac{dv}{dt} = k  \sqrt {t} $

and

$V(t) = \frac{2}{3} k^\frac{3}{2} $

the problem is that if I replace t by 16 so $V (16)$ I find 42.6666...

i am not suppose to find 100 as it says in the states ??

can anyone please help me

Comment: What about the integration constant ?

Comment: V(t) = (2 k^( 3/2 ) / 3 ) + C

Comment: learn Mathjax, I fixed it for you this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write out everything that the problem is giving you as data for an initial value problem. You've done so for sales volume being proportional to the square root of time:

$$
\frac{dV}{dt} = k \sqrt{t}.
$$

Now based on what you stated as the problem, at the time of the start of the marketing there is zero volume. For convenience let's pick that time as $t=0$ so everything is measured from the start of the marketing effort. Then we have a condition $V(0) = 0$. Finally, you stated that 16 months later we have sales volume of 100 and this gives us one last condition $V(16)=100$.

Your solution for $V(t)$ is close but it looks like you have a typo since there is no $t$ in the equation! Separating variables and integrating we get:

$$
\int dV = \int k\sqrt{t} \,dt = k\int t^\frac{1}{2} \,dt \\ 
\rightarrow V = \frac{2}{3}k \, t^\frac{3}{2} + C
$$
where C is our constant of integration.

So we have two unknowns to solve for: $k$ and $C$. For $C$, we use $V(0)=0$ and thus

$$
0 = V(0) = 0 + C \rightarrow C=0.
$$

For $k$ we use the second condition, $V(16)=100$, and we get

$$
100 = \frac{2}{3}k \, (16)^\frac{3}{2} = \frac{2}{3}k(64) = \frac{128}{3}k \\
\rightarrow k = 100\left(\frac{3}{128}\right) = \frac{75}{32},
$$
and thus we have
$$
V(t) = \frac{2}{3} \left( \frac{75}{32}\right) \, t^\frac{3}{2} = \frac{25}{16} t^{3/2}.
$$

I hope this helps.